# Multiply and Integrate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^2},$ $\phi\in L_2, t\in(0,T), T>0$ and $\gamma>0.$

$$ |\xi|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2(t)\leq\gamma\int_{0}^T \left|\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right|_{L_2(\Omega)}^2dt$$

If we multiply with $(T-t)$ and then integrate from 0 to T for t, we have,
$$ \int_0^T(T-t)|\xi|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2(t)dt\leq\frac{1}{2}\gamma\int_{0}^T (T-t)^2\left|\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right|_{L_2(\Omega)}^2dt$$

Can anybody help me with the derivation for the right hand side of the last equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your first inequality is of the form
\begin{align*}
|\xi|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2(t)\leq\gamma\int_{0}^t \left|\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial s}\right|_{L_2(\Omega)}^2ds.
\end{align*}
Then, with integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^T(T-t)|\xi|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2(t)dt &\le \gamma\int_0^T(T-t) dt\int_{0}^t \left|\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial s}\right|_{L_2(\Omega)}^2ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\gamma\int_{0}^T (T-t)^2\left|\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right|_{L_2(\Omega)}^2dt.
\end{align*}